# Mura CMS upgrade from 6 to 6.1 and the site manager screen freezes

Tags: coldfusion, mura

I'm really stumped. Any help greatly appreciated.

We recently upgraded from 6 to 6.1 and ever since it happened it keeps spinning when we click on the sitemanager architectural view and that doesnt appear.

Environment:

- SQL Server 2008
- ColdFusion 9[image]

Attached is the snapshot of it. Please any ideas how we can get around this. Development has come to a halt and we have deadlines approaching.

Comment: Your screenshot seems to be missing

Comment: _"Development has come to a halt and we have deadlines approaching."_ - StackOverflow is a community site. When you want something done quick, consider [commercial support](http://www.getmura.com/support/professional-support/)

Comment: Have you tried restarting your ColdFusion server?

Comment: i have tried restarting server but it did not help.tried appending appreoload and dbupdates to the root but nothing happens.the weird part is the version on the side shows it to be 6 but the ui still seems to be the version 5.4 which we had before. it doesnt look like 6 version